# Release soundPool before load new sound files?

Tags: android, soundpool

Imagine I have this:

```
soundPool.play(soundPool.load(this, R.raw.soundFile1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

But now if i want to play my soundFile2, should i use `soundPool.release()` first?

```
soundPool.play(soundPool.load(this, R.raw.soundFile1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
soundPool.release();
soundPool.play(soundPool.load(this, R.raw.soundFile2, 1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Or simply I can load the new sound file without calling `soundPool.release()`? Like so:

```
soundPool.play(soundPool.load(this, R.raw.soundFile1, 1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
soundPool.play(soundPool.load(this, R.raw.soundFile2, 1), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Comment: That's really up to the library, I don't use it but I'd assume they auto-stop before next-play. At least that's how I'd code modules/addons for people (error proof it a bit).

Comment: Something to maybe note, if anything is being re-used like soundFile1 and 2, you shouldn't release them per-say but keep these values stored for use later like soundPool.play(myepicsoundfile, 1,1,1,0,1);

Comment: Actually, the use of one or another sound file depends on the user configuration (settings activity).

Comment: Okay, so that would be up to you to remove file after completion as it may not ever get used again. If goal is to remove it release should do the trick before playing next track. You'd be right to use the release call first otherwise in later example you're loading the resources and just playing them not clearing anything out in hopes to re-use the in-memory sound.